# how to print subsets of 3 in java?

Tags: java, subset

I am doing a course offered by my college and facing problem in one of the code challenges.

**The question is:**
Write a Java code to print all subsets of size 3.

*Sample Input:*

```
arr_size = 5

arr[] = {1, 7, 3, 4, 9}
```

*Sample Output:*

```
(1, 7, 3) (1, 7, 4) (1, 7, 9) (1, 3, 4) (1, 3, 9) (1, 4, 9)

(7, 3, 4) (7, 3, 9) (7, 4, 9)

(3, 4, 9)
```

**The code I wrote for this:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       // Type your code here
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = in.nextInt();
      int a[] = new int[n];
      for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        a[i] = in.nextInt();
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
          for(int k = j+1; k<n; k++)
          {
            System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + ") ");

          }
        }
        if(i<2)
          System.out.print("\n");
      }
    }
}
```

My output matches with the expected output but the website shows wrong. I don't know where I went wrong. Can anybody help me??

Here is the screenshot of my output and expected output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: 'My output matches' - 'but shows wrong' could explain that ?

Comment: @azro If this is something like a HackerRank question, then the OP might have generated the correct output, but HR still rejected because it uses the brute force approach of three nested loops (which doesn't scale nicely for sets of arbitrary size).

Comment: did you scroll right the output boxes? not shown completely

Comment: I can't see the outputs, but are you really using `( ... )` instead of `{ ... }` for _sets_?

Comment: Maybe, it is just the trailing space that is not present in the expected output that makes the check fail ? Try to only print the final space if your not printing the last element of the line.

Comment: Maybe not the answer to your question but i < 2 check might be a problem for bigger array sizes.

Comment: I have tried all ways possible. Removing trail zeros, modifying i<2. But nothing works. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the three issues mentioned below:

1. **Putting space (at the end) in the following line unconditionally:**

   ```
   System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + ") ");
   ```

   The space should be there only between two subsets but not at the end of a line. Write it as follows:

   ```
   if (j < n - 2) {
       System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + ") ");
   } else {
       System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + ")");
   }
   ```

   If you are comfortable with the ternary operator, you can write it in just one line as follows:

   ```
   System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + (j < n - 2 ? ") " : ")"));
   ```
2. **Wrong number of iterations:**

   The condition in the following declaration is causing the loop to run more than required and as a result, it is also causing the line breaks to be printed even after the required output is finished. Note that if you have `n` elements in the array, the number of lines of output should be only `n-2` and also, the line break should be printed only `n-3` times (the line break for the last line is not necessary).

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   ```

   Replace it with

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++)
   ```
3. **Wrong condition for breaking the line:**

   The following condition is causing the line-break only in case of `i<2` which holds good when you have `5` elements in the array but try with `7` or more elements and you will be able to understand what problem it is causing.

   ```
   if(i<2)
   ```

   Replace it with

   ```
   if (i < n - 3)
   ```

   Apart from this, I also recommend you replace

   ```
   System.out.print("\n");
   ```

   with

   ```
   System.out.println();
   ```

   or with

   ```
   System.out.printf("%n");
   ```

   because the recommended versions output line breaks using the platform's preferred line separator whereas `System.out.print("\n")` is a brute force way (i.e. forcing the system to use `\n` as the line separator) which may be a problem for some platforms.

   The following code incorporates all these suggestions:

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   class Main {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
           Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
           int n = in.nextInt();
           int a[] = new int[n];
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
               a[i] = in.nextInt();
           for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) {
               for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                   for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++) {
                       System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + (j < n - 2 ? ") " : ")"));
                   }
               }
               if (i < n - 3)
                   System.out.println();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   **A sample run:**

   ```
   7
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   (1, 2, 3) (1, 2, 4) (1, 2, 5) (1, 2, 6) (1, 2, 7) (1, 3, 4) (1, 3, 5) (1, 3, 6) (1, 3, 7) (1, 4, 5) (1, 4, 6) (1, 4, 7) (1, 5, 6) (1, 5, 7) (1, 6, 7)
   (2, 3, 4) (2, 3, 5) (2, 3, 6) (2, 3, 7) (2, 4, 5) (2, 4, 6) (2, 4, 7) (2, 5, 6) (2, 5, 7) (2, 6, 7)
   (3, 4, 5) (3, 4, 6) (3, 4, 7) (3, 5, 6) (3, 5, 7) (3, 6, 7)
   (4, 5, 6) (4, 5, 7) (4, 6, 7)
   (5, 6, 7)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the idea of matching **not print ending space in case of the last pair in the line**

Check the following sample

```
for(int i=0 ; i<a.length; i++){
    for(int j=i+1 ; j<a.length; j++){
        for(int k=j+1 ; k<a.length; k++){
            // print the 3 elements
            System.out.print("(" + a[i] + ", " + a[j] + ", " + a[k] + ")");

            // not print ending space in case of the last pair in th line  
            if( ! (j==a.length-2 && k == a.length-1) ){
               System.out.print(" "); 
            }
        }
    }
    if(i<2) {
        System.out.println();   
    }
}
```